# Graph surgery after loading from file using saved_model loader

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to add a data pipeline using the Dataset API to an existing graph. The model has been loaded using the `tf.saved_model.loader.load` method. I am able to provide input using `feed_dict`, however this is slow compared to the Dataset API.

I am able to load the graph, capture the input/output nodes by name, and evaluate the graph by passing the data into it via `feed_dict`.

This is what I have so far

```py
export_dir = "/path/to/saved/model"
img = load_as_numpy_array("/path/to/image/file")

with tf.Graph.as_default() :
    with tf.Session() as sess :
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, tf.saved_model.tag_constants.TRAINING], export_dir)

        #unique identifiers for this specific model
        input_name = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if "hub_input" in n.name][0]
        output_name = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if "hub_output" in n.name][0]

        input_operation = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(input_name)
        output_operation = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(output_name)

        result = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], feed_dict={input_operation.outputs[0]: img})
        print(result)
```

In the past I have always done it something like this, using `tf.import_graph_def` and an `input_map`

```
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={"MyInputTensor": input})
```

However there does not seem to be a supported way to use this or similar functionality with `tf.saved_model.loader`